# ASP.NET Core DI different options instance depending on requesting class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've used Autofac in the past and while sometimes it can be a bit complicated it has never lacked in features I needed.  Now I'm trying to use the built-in dependency injection in ASP.NET Core and am having trouble achieving the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  // Use these settings by default
  services.Configure<EmailerSettings>(Configuration.GetSettings("DefaultEmailer"));

  // Would like to specify different settings that apply to the SpecialEmailer class only
  //services.Configure<EmailerSettings>(Configuration.GetSettings("SpecialEmailer"));
}
```

**Classes that depend on DI**

```
public class Emailer {
    public Emailer(IOptions<EmailerSettings> settings) {
       // Should get the default settings
    }
}

public class SpecialEmailer {
    public SpecialEmailer(IOptions<EmailerSettings> settings) {
       // Should get the special settings
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this with the out of the box DI?  I could of course create `SpecialEmailerSettings` and use that in the `SpecialEmailer` class, but the structure is identical so I'd like to reuse if possible.

Comment: So why not use Autofac than?

Comment: Also, prevent injecting `IOptions<T>` in your application components, as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioptions-t).

Comment: @Steven: Yeah, I already have the code using `Bind()`, which is another method in `ConfigurationBinder` alongside the `Get<T>()` from the post you linked to to achieve the same result.  Before considering changing to Autofac I wanted to see if the built-in DI supported something like this.  I'd rather not introduce another dependency unless I have a good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that, but I don't think that any of them is elegant as you're hoping for. I guess your best bet is to create another settings model `SpecialEmailerSettings` that inherits from `EmailerSettings`. I know that you've already thought of this and you wanted to reuse, but I think inheritance is one way of reusing. It's just one extra line:

```
public class SpecialEmailerSettings : EmailerSettings { }
```

Then load it like this:

```
services.Configure<EmailerSettings>(Configuration.GetSettings("DefaultEmailer"));
services.Configure<SpecialEmailerSettings>(Configuration.GetSettings("SpecialEmailer"));
```

And finally use it in your class:

```
public class SpecialEmailer {
    public SpecialEmailer(IOptions<SpecialEmailerSettings> settings) {
       // Should get the special settings
    }
}
```